# Python - raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary, append

I gathered live tweets for an hour before the recent Champions League match between Juventus and Atlético Madrid.

```
#setting tweepy up
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
translator = Translator()


#gathering live tweets with probable hashtags for the fixture for an hour before the game starts
class Listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, status):
        print(status)
        with open('Juve_vs_AthMadrid.json', 'a') as f:
            f.write(status)
        return True
    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True

twitter_stream = Stream(auth, Listener())
twitter_stream.filter(track=['#Juve', '#juve', '#JuveAtleti', '#turin',
                             '#AúpaAtleti', '#ForzaJuve', '#AtléticosAroundTheWorld!', '#VamosAtleti',
                             '#AtléticosPorElMundo'])
```

Next, I proceeded to clean the data. I created a list with each tweet dictionary (as a string) in it and tried to convert these strings into actual python dictionaries using the **json.loads function**

```
handle = open('Juve_vs_AthMadrid.json', 'r')
file = handle.readlines()
handle.close()
dic_list = []
for dic_str in file:
    dic_list.append(json.loads(dic_str))
```

However, I keep getting **raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None** error on line `dic_list.append(json.loads(dic_str))`

Answer (score 3):

Example of reading a JSON file and storing the data in a Python dictionary:

`example.py`:

```
import json
with open("example.json", "r") as json_data:
  data = json.loads(json_data.read())
  print(type(data))
  print(data)
```

`example.json`:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<class 'dict'>
{'glossary': {'GlossDiv': {'GlossList': {'GlossEntry': {'SortAs': 'SGML', 'Abbrev': 'ISO 8879:1986', 'ID': 'SGML', 'GlossTerm': 'Standard Generalized Markup Language', 'GlossDef': {'GlossSeeAlso': ['GML', 'XML'], 'para': 'A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.'}, 'GlossSee': 'markup', 'Acronym': 'SGML'}}, 'title': 'S'}, 'title': 'example glossary'}}
```

The output shows that `data` is `dict` type.

Comment: You beat me to it, the issue ultimately boils down to `readlines()` vs `read()`. +1 from me